# ConnectEx fails with WSAEISCONN after calling DisconnectEx with TF_REUSE_SOCKET

Tags: c++, winapi, iocp

I have an IOCP based client for which I wanted to implement HTTP redirects in a following way:

1) When encountering a redirect to a different host call `DisconnectEx` with `TF_REUSE_SOCKET`

2) Await the overlapped completion and then call `ConnectEx`

However my code gets a `WSAEISCONN` return code upon calling `ConnectEx` even though if I check `GetLastError()` when the overlapped result of `DisconnectEx` is returned it gives 0.

An MVCE would be quite big in this case, but if there are no experience based suggestions I'll post one.

***Update***

I tried to make a MVCE but encountered different symptoms:

```
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

static inline std::string ErrorMessage(const char* pErrorMessage, ...)
{
    std::string sFormattedMessage;
    va_list VariableArgumentList;
    va_start(VariableArgumentList, pErrorMessage);
    sFormattedMessage.resize(_vscprintf(pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentList) + 1);
    vsnprintf_s(const_cast<char*>(sFormattedMessage.c_str()), sFormattedMessage.size(), sFormattedMessage.size(), pErrorMessage, VariableArgumentList);
    va_end(VariableArgumentList);
    return sFormattedMessage;
}

#define CHECK(x, format, ...) { if ((x) == false)  throw std::runtime_error(ErrorMessage("%s(%d): "format, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)); }

template<typename T>
bool LoadWinsockExtensionFunction(SOCKET Socket, GUID Guid, T* pFunction)
{
    DWORD nBytesReturned = 0;
    return WSAIoctl(Socket, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &Guid, sizeof(Guid), pFunction, sizeof(T), &nBytesReturned, NULL, NULL) == 0 && nBytesReturned == sizeof(T);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        WORD nRequestedWinsockVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        WSADATA WsaData;
        CHECK(WSAStartup(nRequestedWinsockVersion, &WsaData) == 0, "WSAStartup failed");
        auto hCompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, NULL, 0);
        CHECK(hCompletionPort != NULL, "CreateIoCompletionPort failed(%d)", GetLastError());
        auto Socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
        CHECK(Socket != INVALID_SOCKET, "WSASocket failed(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
        CHECK(CreateIoCompletionPort(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(Socket), hCompletionPort, NULL, 0), "CreateIoCompletionPort failed(%d)", GetLastError());
        sockaddr_in LocalAddress;
        ZeroMemory(&LocalAddress, sizeof(LocalAddress));
        LocalAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        LocalAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        LocalAddress.sin_port = 0;
        CHECK(bind(Socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&LocalAddress), sizeof(LocalAddress)) == 0, "bind failed(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
        LPFN_CONNECTEX pConnectEx = nullptr;
        CHECK(LoadWinsockExtensionFunction(Socket, WSAID_CONNECTEX, &pConnectEx), "WSAIoctl failed to load ConnectEx(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
        LPFN_DISCONNECTEX pDisconnectEx = nullptr;
        CHECK(LoadWinsockExtensionFunction(Socket, WSAID_DISCONNECTEX, &pDisconnectEx), "WSAIoctl failed to load DisconnectEx(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
        addrinfo Hint;
        ZeroMemory(&Hint, sizeof(Hint));
        Hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
        Hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        Hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        std::map<std::string, PADDRINFOA> Hosts;
        // Scenarios:
        // one host - failure to connect on the second try to the first host with 52
        // two distinct hosts - failure to connect on the second try to the first host with 52
        Hosts.emplace("www.google.com", nullptr);
        Hosts.emplace("www.facebook.com", nullptr);
        for (auto& Host : Hosts)
        {
            auto nGetAddressInfoResult = getaddrinfo(Host.first.c_str(), "http", &Hint, &Host.second);
            CHECK(nGetAddressInfoResult == 0 && &Host.second, "getaddrinfo failed(%d)", nGetAddressInfoResult);
        }
        auto Host = Hosts.begin();
        WSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped;
        ZeroMemory(&Overlapped, sizeof(Overlapped));
        while (true)
        {
            if ((*pConnectEx)(Socket, Host->second->ai_addr, Host->second->ai_addrlen, nullptr, 0, nullptr, &Overlapped) == FALSE)
            {
                auto nWSAError = WSAGetLastError();
                CHECK(nWSAError == ERROR_IO_PENDING, "ConnectEx failed(%d)", nWSAError);
                DWORD nBytesTransferred = 0;
                ULONG_PTR pCompletionKey = 0;
                LPOVERLAPPED pOverlapped = nullptr;
                CHECK(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &nBytesTransferred, &pCompletionKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE), "overlapped operation failed(%d)", GetLastError());
            }
            CHECK(setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT, NULL, 0) == 0, "setsockopt failed(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
            CHECK(shutdown(Socket, SD_BOTH) == 0, "shutdown failed(%d)", WSAGetLastError());
            if ((*pDisconnectEx)(Socket, &Overlapped, TF_REUSE_SOCKET, 0) == FALSE)
            {
                auto nWSAError = WSAGetLastError();
                CHECK(nWSAError == ERROR_IO_PENDING, "ConnectEx failed(%d)", nWSAError);
                DWORD nBytesTransferred = 0;
                ULONG_PTR pCompletionKey = 0;
                LPOVERLAPPED pOverlapped = nullptr;
                CHECK(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &nBytesTransferred, &pCompletionKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE), "overlapped operation failed(%d)", GetLastError());
            }
            if (++Host == Hosts.end())
            {
                Host = Hosts.begin();
            }
        }
        closesocket(Socket);
        CloseHandle(hCompletionPort);
        for (auto& Host : Hosts)
        {
            freeaddrinfo(Host.second);
        }
        WSACleanup();
    }
    catch (std::exception& Exception)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA(Exception.what());
        std::cout << Exception.what();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With this snippet what happens is that I get `ERROR_DUP_NAME` on the second attempt to connect to the same host (`TIME_WAIT` possibly?). I assume that if I could rebind the socket (but I can't since a second `bind` call fails with `WSAEINVAL` which is correct since the socket is already bound) this could even work fine.

What I have in my original code is a redirect from `localhost` to the actual address of the interface - maybe there simply is a path which in that case gives out `WSAEISCONN` instead of `ERROR_DUP_NAME` ? I can't post an MVCE for the original code since then another piece of code that would accept the connections is needed (maybe I'll make one).

I actually found that if `DisconnectEx` is called by the client then yes, `ERROR_DUP_NAME` happens because of `TIME_WAIT` (see [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/432292-disconnectex-and-socket-re-use/) for a detailed analysis). So the bottom line is I should simply not try to reuse sockets in this scenario.

Comment: Per the [`ConnectEx` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx): "***Any attempt to reconnect an active connection will fail with the error code WSAEISCONN**... If the `DisconnectEx` function is called with the `TF_REUSE_SOCKET` flag, **the specified socket is returned to a state in which it is not connected**, but still bound. In such cases, the handle of the socket can be passed to the `ConnectEx` function in its `s` parameter.*"...

Comment: ... are you *absolutely sure* you are waiting for `DisconnectEx()` to fully finish before calling `ConnectEx()`? Are you *absolutely sure* you are passing the correct `SOCKET` from `DisconnectEx()` to `ConnectEx()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I am:) But after thorough reading of MSDN I have stumbled upon the fact that maybe I still need to call `shutdown` before `DisconnectEx` (I was not doing that since it is mentioned nowhere in the `DisconnectEx` page). Will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it's not entirely clear to me how `TIME_WAIT` is implemented.  If `DisconnectEx` returns while the socket is still in the `TIME_WAIT` state then you won't be able to connect to a different host using that socket until the wait delay has expired.

Comment: @HarryJohnston that is another thing I stumbled upon while reading MSDN, but since there is no clear way to check if the TIME_WAIT period has elapsed I'll just hope `shutdown` will do the trick.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tried to make an MVCE and it seems that when I use two distinct hosts (in my case the redirect was from localhost to the physical address of the interface) I get `ERROR_DUP_NAME` which is different and could be related to `TIME_WAIT`.